# Error in sending email using gmail smtp in Django app

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-email

I set up everything as the Django documentation but when I test sending an email.It works but When I check my inbox I find out that I sent and revived from to the same email address.

Here is the settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "myemail@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypassword"
```

And the views.py

```
...
send_mail( 'subject', 'message', 'user@gmail.com', ['myemail@gmail.com',], fail_silently=False, )
...
```

But I received an email from myemail@gmail.com to me(myemail@gmail.com).

Comment: describe what did you think it would happen https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#send-mail

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: what is your desired behaviour

Comment: I want just to fix that and btw my project is live

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve it is unclear, you cannot send mail by pretending to be other user using gmail

Comment: One point to think about: the far majority of people here on SO having trouble to send email from their servers is using Gmail.

Comment: Are you really using the unix program "sendmail" which you tagged this as?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you did this already but if youre using gmail then you will need to do the following.

```
Sign in to your Google Admin console (Sign in using an administrator account)
Click Security > Less secure apps.
Select Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps.
Click Save.25
```

Also you should use environment variables for the email address if you are live already eg:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('MY_EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MY_EMAIL_PASS')
```

If its all working and you are just getting the mail to the wrong address can you send  on the document you followed?

In terms of you settings.py that looks fine to me.